# How to use Azure AD for authentication?

Tags: authentication

What is the best method to authenticate users against Azure AD when trying to access WP? Doing some search I have come across sites like:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/sso-with-azure-ad/ .

https://wordpress.org/plugins/daggerhart-openid-connect-generic/

https://www.miniorange.com/step-by-step-guide-to-set-up-azure-ad-as-idp-for-wordpress

and would like to know what is the best way. Will a plugin be necessary or is this not something supported out of the box with official WP?

Comment: "is this not something supported out of the box with official WP?" - no, it only supports authentication against its own database. You will need a plugin, yes.